# 2006 Honda fit cold engine indicator still on even after long drive

Tags: repair, cold-weather

I have a 2006 honda fit with a 1.3L I-DSI engine, the cold engine indicator still shows itself even after a long drive, normally, it disappears minutes after startup regardless of weather and theres no snow where im from. There was one time where i just had a short stop but the car wont start, i had hold the pedal to the floor while cranking the engine, after it started the idle rpm was at 1500. I know rpms are high during a cold start but this time its already warm.

---

What i tried: 
I started the car and let it warm itself up before going, surprisingly, the indicator disappeared only to reappear after a short drive. It sometimes disappears for a moment then its back again. I used a scan tool but no codes rendered and the coolant temp is at 36°C.

Whats causing this? a faulty sensor? if so what sensor is it? can it be replaced? (It first happened on a cold rainy night while i was driving)

READ FIRST:
as i reviewed my question, i now discovered that its very confusing (sorry about that, english is not my mother tongue) the problem is basically the cold engine indicator still flashes itself despite the engine being plenty warm after 30 minutes of driving and its causing rough startups and high idle rpms at 1500rpm even though the engine is already warm. (the rough startup only happened once tho)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here since you seem to be discussing at least two different issues at the same time.  But with respect to the COLD part of your question, it's important to know if the engine is really cold or it's up to temperature and the indicator is reading cold anyway.  In the first case the prime suspect is the THERMOSTAT.  These often fail in the OPEN position and cause too much water to go to the radiator.  The second case is a TEMP SENSOR problem.  Check and replace the sensor.

Comment: That's an answer @jwh20

Comment: Thanks for the response @jwh20. I tried searching at google for someone with the same issue but i found nothing thus, here I am. I will look into  everything you just told and i hope its not a major issue